# Rails 3.1 nested forms validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I'm using Formtastic 2 for a nested form - I have a menus and a meals model, menus have many meals, every meal belongs to one menu.
I added the meal form to the menu show action, right below a list of already associated meals.

Creating meals works fine if validation succeeds, I forward to the menu show action again listing the created meal in the list.

But when the meals doesn't get validated and I forward to the menu show action again with an appropriate flash message, I would really like to fill the form with the data that was submitted before and rendering the errors next to it.

I tried with this redirect:

```
redirect_to(menu_path(menu,@meal), :alert => 'The meal was not created')
```

But I can't get at the meal variable and passing it back to the form this way, the request itself is a GET request with only the menu id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't redirect after validation errors, because you'll lose all state. Just the old template directly after a failed validation. A little gotcha is that you need to use `flash.now[:alert]`, so it won't carry over to the next page.

Usually you'll have this *structure*:

```
def new
  @meal = Meal.new
end

def create
  @meal = Meal.new(params[:meal])
  if @meal.save
    flash[:notice] = "Meal was created"
    redirect_to menu_path(menu, @meal)
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "The meal was not created"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: You are right, though I found out that my initial problem was a misunderstanding of the controller structure. I had a MenuController and a MealController with a complete CRUD - but when adding meals in the menu show action, the code for adding the meal should probably be in the MenuController when this is the only place meals get created. The I can get rid of the MealController alltogether.